# Get previous page URL, Open New Window, then Redirect through Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm stuck using a CMS that only gives me the ability to modify the content of the `<body>`, so when I want to redirect people, I've used this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.example.com/"
</script>
```

So, yes, the page loads first, and then 5ms later, the redirect happens, and it's worked for all intensive purposes.  Now, I'm wondering if I can use javascript to do something else.

Is it possible to open a new browser tab, with a specified URL, and then redirect the user back to the previous page, through Javascript?

Many thanks, SO.

EDIT - Whether it opens a new window or tab, to be honest, is not as important as it actually functioning.  I need Javascript to determine the prior page (if possible), then open a new window/tab to a URL I specify, and then redirect the current window/tab to it's prior page.  Some are saying that `window.open` only works on a click event, which will not work for what I am trying accomplish either... just fyi.

So, literally, without clicks, I need Javascript to do the following -

1. Determine the prior/previous/last page the user came from, store it as a variable
2. Open a new window or tab, to a specified URL
3. `window.location` back to the prior page, which I stored as a variable

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: `window.open` might be what you are looking for. It's not new tab but might be what you are looking for.

Comment: before you spend much time troubleshooting with window.open, remember that it can only be executed from a user action such as a mouse click.

Comment: so, in that regard, can I have `window.open = "http://www.example.com"; window.location = priorpage;` and then use javascript to determine what `var priorpage` would be?

Comment: ooops.... good call then @Salketer

Comment: see [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: also, window.open is pretty much a pop-blocking haven...

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do... You want to click a link that goes to a page with JS that opens a window and then goes back to previous page?

Comment: No clicks.  Above shows an instantenous redirect, because I cannot touch the `header` of the page.  I want to open a new window/tab of a specified URL, then redirect the current window/tab to it's previous page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the user's browser setting using `window.open` can open the new window in a new tab instead but you CANNOT directly control this through the browser. It is all down to the user's settings.

To open a new window:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", "windowName", "window options (optional parameter)");
```

Then simply use:

```
history.back();
```

You can also use the referer property:

```
var previousUrl = document.referrer;
```

For more info on `window.open`, see: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

For more info on the document.referrer property, take a look at: http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/javascript_no14.htm

Comment: Ok.  Opening a new tab or window are both acceptable in this case.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer =] window.open might get blocked by the user's popup blocker, however SharePoint should already be in the local intranet zone or trusted sites so you should be alright.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to retrieve the last page the visitor was on before this page?  I could store that as `mySavedUrl`, for the purpose of returning them to the page they were before.

Comment: I've also added in some info about document.referrer as using history.back can send you to a page that needs form re-submission which could confuse users or do things you don't want by having them re-post form data.